# Is there a word for a person that is tender, as well as strict?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word for a person that is tender as well as strict at times or as per situation?

A word that could be used for a teacher or maybe a mother.

> Although she was (like)  ________, she was the best.

I usually compare them to being like a coconut (hard from the outside but soft in the inside) since I don't have a better alternative.

Please add suitable idioms if available, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: The word paternal might work. It gives the sense of someone who is tender but firm, as father-figures often are, but sounds a little unusual when referring to a female. It may have to be be qualified as 'more paternal than maternal'.

Comment: *gruff but lovable* is the phrase that comes to mind.

Comment: The indicated duplicate does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact synonym but we can call such person as 'Coconut'. I know I'm using simile figure of speech here.

Coconut is hard outside but soft and sweet within!

Comment: I am glad that u found some time to answer this, however i have included the same in my description, do reply if u have a better alternative.

Comment: Yeah it's my fault that I didn't read complete question by you. Anyways, we can say such person using simile again and can call as, Jackfruit! E.g. The person was a Jackfruit. Weird, hard outside but sweet within.

Answer (score 0):

You might say that

- although she *practiced tough love*, she was the best.

> Tough love is an expression used when someone treats another person harshly or sternly with the intent to help them in the long run.
>
> In most uses, there must be some actual love or feeling of affection behind the harsh or stern treatment to be defined as tough love. For example, genuinely concerned parents refusing to support their drug-addicted child financially until he or she enters drug rehabilitation would be said to be practicing tough love.
>
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_love)

Note the qualification that "there must be some actual love or feeling of affection". (Note also that simply *calling* a pattern of behaviour *tough love* isn't enough to make it qualify as such.)

Comment: I am glad that u engaged your valuable time to answer this, i would surely help me in some situations, though i am looking for a word that may fit in any situation, No doubt it suites well for the sample sentence.